# WCF documentation for JSON and XML

Tags: xml, json, wcf, documentation-generation

I am using [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/releases/view/81770)  for WCF documentation. It is creating perfect documentation for SOAP and C#. I have also 2 other endpoints which are JSON and XML.
is there any way to generate documentation for those endpoints also?
Like get request samples etc?

Thanks.